# Prove card(P(N)) = card(Q)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A homework problem for my class.  I've read multiple sources online (i.e. https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof2/Cardinality.pdf) and even went to my univeristy tutor center who was unable to help me and referred me back to the professor.

Can someone please explain how to solve this in the most simplest terms for a complete dummy to proofs?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $\varphi:A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N})\mapsto 1_A\in\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{N},\{0,1\})$ is a bijection where $1_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ if not. In fact, $\varphi^{-1}:f\in\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{N},\{0,1\})\mapsto f^{-1}(\{1\})\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N})$.

Comment: thanks see that's my problem.  I can't take what you just wrote even as an answer, then understand how you came to that, or what that even reads in english.  Any chance you can dumb that answer down a bit?

Comment: Ok sorry, you can show that there is a bijection between $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{N},\{0,1\})$ (the set of function from $\mathcal{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$) and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N})$. If $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N})$, I define $\varphi(A)=1_{A}$ as i defined it previously. If $1_A=1_B$ then $A=B$ because if $x\in A$, $1_B(x)=1_A(x)=1$ so $x\in B$ and by the same argument, if $x\in B$, $x\in A$. If $f\in\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{N},\{0,1\})$, let $A=\{x\in\mathcal{N}\ |\ f(x)=1\}$, then $f=1_A$ by definition of $1_A$.

Comment: In the end $\varphi$ is a bijection, each element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N})$ has exactly one analogous object in $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{N},\{0,1\})$ so they have the same cardinal.

Answer (score 1):

Given a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$, and an natural number $m$, you can ask: Is $m$ in $S$? Then let $f_S(m)$ be the answer, which is either "yes, it's in the set $S$" if $m\in S$, and "no, it's not in the set $S$" if $m\notin S$.

Notice that if $S$ and $T$ are subsets, you will get the same function, $f_S=f_T$, if and only if both always give the same answer, if and only if for every natural number $m$, either $m$ is in both $S$ and $T$, or $m$ is in *neither* $S$ and $T$; that is, if and only if $S=T$.

So these functions characterize the subsets: given the function, you know exactly who the subset is; given the subset, you know exactly what the function is.

Now, being lazy mathematicians that we are, we don't want to say "yes, it's in the set $S$" every time the answer is "yes"; and we don't want to say "no, it's not in the set $S$" every time the answer is "no." So how about using "$1$" as shorthand for "yes, it's in the set $S$", and "$0$" as shorthand for "no, it's not in the set $S$"? That is,
$$f_S(m) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{if }m\in S,\\
0 & \text{if }m\notin S.
\end{array}\right.$$

I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: thanks that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

A simple bijection between $Q$ and $\mathcal P(\mathcal N)$ is $f\mapsto f^{-1}(1)$, or in other words, the subset of $\mathcal N$ that $f$ maps to $1$.

Proof that it is a bijection:

Injective: If $f_1\neq f_2$, there has to exist some $n\in\mathcal N$ such that $f_1(n)\neq f_2(n)$. Hence, either $f_1(n)=0,\;f_2(n)=1$, or vice versa. By symmetry, assume that $f_1(n)=0,\;f_2(n)=1$. Then, $n\notin f_1^{-1}(1),\;n\in f_2^{-1}(1)$, so $f_1^{-1}(1)\neq f_2^{-1}(1)$.

Surjective: Given $A\subseteq\mathcal N$, let $f:\mathcal N\to\{0,1\}$ be $$f(n)=\begin{cases}0&n\notin A\\1&n\in A\end{cases}$$It is easy to see that $f^{-1}(1)=A$.